# Не грузятся статические файлы

Tags: apache, .htaccess, django

Не грузятся статические файлы, при обращении к site.ru/static сообщение об ошибке, что /static не прописано в urls.py. На боевой сервер ставлю Django. На сервере стоит Apache + mod_wsgi

Файл .htaccess

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Файл index.wsgi

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/django')
sys.path.append('/home/c/cl14188/portal/public_html')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'portal.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

В settings.py все настройки статики по умолчанию. Как я понимаю, лучший вариант добавить правило в .htaccess, но ничего по этому поводу не нашёл :(

Comment: А, собственно, где само описание проблемы, что не работает?

Comment: Не грузятся статические файлы при обращении к site.ru/static сообщение об ошибке что /static не прописано в urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/static` должно обрабатываться Апачем, а не Джангой. То есть надо в конфигурацию добавить

```
Alias /static /home/c/cl14188/portal/public_html/static
```

ну или какие уж там правильные директории.